# zf2 AbstractRestfullController API routing

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I am pretty new to zf2.  I am trying to build a RESTful API for our contact management system.  We are extending the `AbstractRestfulController` which uses `getList()`, `get()`, etc actions.

Everything works as I would expect it to with the exception of one url route.  When I go to this url

```
/contacts
```

it successfully routes to the `getList()` method of my `ContactsController`.  However when I go here.

```
/contacts/1253378/stats
```

it routes to the `get()` method of my `StatsController`.  I would expect that url to route to the `getList()` method, which I would then return a list of stats.

I would expect adding an `/idnumber` to the end of that url would route to the `get()` method of my `StatsController`, which would return one stat with that id.

Basically I am trying to replicate what is laid out in this REST tutorial, under the `But how do you deal with relations` section.

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful

I am hoping my routes are not correct in my `module.config.php` file

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'contacts' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/contacts[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Contacts\Controller\ContactsController',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'stats' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/contacts/[:id]/stats[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Contacts\Controller\StatsController',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just saying you might want to consider Apigility over zf2... https://apigility.org ... it's developed by Zend and uses the same concepts etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check that out for my side projects, looks pretty cool.  Unfortunately I don't really have a say in what I use at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case problem is that `id` parameter conflicts, recommended way is to use specific parameter names, eg:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
       'contacts' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
               'route'    => '/contacts[/:contactId]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'contactId'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Contacts\Controller\ContactsController',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'stats' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                       'route'    => '/stats[/:statId]',
                       'constraints' => array(
                            'statId'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Contacts\Controller\StatsController',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Url `/contacts/1253378/stats` will match `contacts/stats` route with `contactId` set to `1253378`

To make that change work, you will need to set protected property `identifierName` in `Contacts\Controller\ContactsController` to 'contactId' and in `Contacts\Controller\StatsController` to `statId`

Now controllers will properly use separate variables for Id and everything should work fine.

Comment: Awesome!!! thank you very much.  This works exactly the way I need it to, with the exception that `child-routes` should be `child_routes`.  I learned quite a bit more about zf2 from this answer. Wish I could give you more than one upvote!